# Using pointers with a class instance in c#

Tags: c#

I recently switched over from C++ to C# and I am wondering how I would do the equivalent in c#.  In C++ I could have done this:

```
Enemy *enemy; 

enemy = new Enemy("Goblin", 20, 20);
```

In c#, I tried the pointer methond and using a delegate and both failed. The thing is I have multiple enemys in my Text RPG and I need to assign a specific enemy to my enemy pointer class so I then can preform the battle processes.

Answer (score 4):

C# has references instead of C++ style pointers. So for your example, you would just do:

```
Enemy enemy; //enemy is a reference to an Enemy
enemy = new Enemy("Goblin", 20, 20); //the reference points to a Enemy instance in the heap
```

Another interesting difference is that **almost everything is a reference**, apart from some primitive value types (`int`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, structs, enumerations) which can be stored on the stack.

Comment: As a side note you CAN use pointers, however they are considered unsafe and you have to mark your code as such - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Value types are only stored on the stack when they are local variables, otherwise they are part of an object which is stored on the heap.

Comment: @user2097371 ipavlic's sample works because in C# classes are passed by reference, not by value. An excelent article to understand this relationship is this one about the difference between Class and Struct in C# http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/29/c-fundamentals-the-differences-between-struct-and-class.aspx

Comment: @EtherDragon: No, references are not passed by reference unless you use the `ref` keyword. Passing a reference and passing *by* reference is two different things.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would be that simple.